# web scraping and transferring data excel python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm able to fully **scrape** the material I needed the problem is I can't get the data into `Excel`.

Here is my code: (Everything works)

```
def scrape_data(card):
    try:
        h2 = card.h2
    except:
        title = ''
    else:
        title = h2.text.strip()

    try:       
        price = card.find('span', class_='a-offscreen').text
    except:
        price = ''
    else:
        price = card.find('span', class_='a-offscreen').text
    

    data = {'Titulo':title,  'Preco': price}

    return data


def main():
        url = 'https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=iphone'
        html = get_html(url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

        cards = soup.find_all('div', {'data-asin':True, 'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})
        
        ads_data = []
        for card in cards:
            data = scrape_data(card)
            ads_data.append(data)
        
        write_xlsx(ads_data)
```

But I'm stuck here , I don't know how to iterate dictionary on `Excel` file...

```
def write_xlsx(ads):
    with xlsxwriter.Workbook('results.xlsx') as workbook:

        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        
        worksheet.write(0,0,'Titulo')
        worksheet.write(0,1,'Preco')
    
    for i,(k,v) in enumerate(ads.items(),start=1):
        worksheet.write(i,0,k)
        worksheet.write(i,0,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is simply to iterate over the entry of the dict i think i can help you with this:

```
items = ads.items()
for i in range(1, len(items)):
    k, v = items[i]
    worksheet.write(i, 0, k)
    worksheet.write(i, 0, v)
```

I think you are overcomplicating things. :)